# Exporting Designs for different social media platforms without losing aspect ratio

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am designing posts for different social media Platforms like Facebook and Instagram as well as LinkedIn and Illustrator. My question is that how to export the same design for multiple social media platforms without losing aspect ratio. [image]

The above image is designed for Facebook on the resolution of 1200*628

As when I try to export the same image for Instagram that is 1080*1080 resolution I am losing aspect ratio and you can see clearly that below image is not in a crisp shape and the graphics are like suffocating.

[image]

My question is how professionals handle this situation, and how to export designs for various social media platforms without losing the aspect ratio of designs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rework for specific sizes**.

In general, if *anything* needs to work in varying proportions. I feel, the best solution is to actually *rework* the piece to match the given proportions.

Marketing firms or higher-end companies do *not* try and use a single image for everything. They create **multiple images** based upon need. This is really the *only* way you can ensure branding and user impressions remain consistent.

Just as you would not try and force a "one page" or "flyer" to work on a billboard by merely resizing, you should not try and *force* the same advertisement to work for every conceivable outlet.

Create multiple images using the same content.

The minor amount of time necessary to rework the content will be directly reflected in the ROI of a better formatted image for a given outlet.

---

Moved from comments to clarify...

If reworking required you to edit everything 5 or 6 more times, you edit every bit 5 or 6 times. That's how it's done. Anything short of that is less than ideal. Typically, if someone were *paying* a marketing firm to advertise for them, they would be displeased with one image stretched and containing 50% white space rather than being *designed to fit the advertising space allotted*. Professionals rework the content to fit the space.

The point would be as a *paying* advertiser I've *shelled out my money* for a particular advertising space. *It costs me money*. A designer looking for shortcuts to save them work and delivering artwork that is only utilizing 50-60% of the space *I am paying for*, is **not** doing me any service. I'd look for a designer which understands *advertising costs me money* and I don't want to pay for 40% *blank background* merely because the designer didn't want to do a little extra work.

---

In addition, as the **designer**, you *charge the client* for the time needed to rework the content to fit various advertisers. I wouldn't do it for free. There would be an initial design fee then an additional $X amount for each *different* advertiser or size requiring a rework. Using *random figures*, that would be something like $300 for the design, then $50 per size/advertiser.

Comment: Suppose i need to make as same advertisement for like 5 or 6 different platforms, then don't you that it will be a time consuming task. You have to edit every bit of work for every proportion. Rather then you can make a single image and re-edit for various platforms.

Comment: Well now i am being satisfied. For my next post i am developing two art-boards one art-board for FB and the other for Instagram. Rather then stretching it or adding white space to it. I have already think the same before posting the question on this platform, then i think that illustrator is a powerful tool and maybe i will find another way to do things. Well @Scott clarified it especially mentioning the cost factor in it, and how professionals will handle the scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I would try making the original design into a square frame, leaving as less side margins as possible, with this you have solved the square ratio. Expanding the side bleeding objects and background to a maximum rectangle size, you have all the rectangle ratios. I guess the differences between the square and all the other ratios are not as exaggerated as shown in this illustration:

[image: ratios]

Getting all the background objects in different layers, show and hide each layer to select all and export the correspondent ratio design post:

[image: layers]

Answer (score 2):

By adding in **whitespace**...

You could add whitespace on top and bottom to make it a square:

> [image: whitespace]

The whitespace can even be an extension of the background color:

> [image: pinkspace]